# Ajax Call get null value in backing bean in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have two SelectoneMenu and one inputText. within inputText I called one Ajax event(blur). But this ajax method does not get selected value from SelectoneMenu. But I called the same method using CommandButton it will get selected values and worked fine.

Here is My Code:

```
<h:form id=HarvestRateForm>
<table width="670px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100px;"><p:outputLabel value="Crushing Season" for="crushingSeason"/></td>
                            <td width="80px;">
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="crushingSeason" style="width: 110px;" value="#{harvestRateBean.selectedSeason}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select"/>
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{harvestRateBean.seasons}"/>
                                </p:selectOneMenu><p:growl for="crushingSeason"/>
                            </td>
                            <td width="60px;" align="right"><p:outputLabel value="Plant" for="plant"/></td>
                            <td width="80px;"><p:selectOneMenu id="plant" style="width: 85px;" value="#{harvestRateBean.selectedPlant}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select"/>
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{harvestRateBean.plants}"/>
                                </p:selectOneMenu><p:growl for="plant"/></td>
                            <td width="60px;" align="right"><p:outputLabel value="Plot No" for="plotNo"/></td>
                            <td><p:inputText id="plotNo" value="#{harvestRateBean.sapPlotNo}" size="16"> 
                                    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{harvestRateBean.loadPlotDetails}"
                                            update="HarvestRateForm:plotNo HarvestRateForm:ryotCode"/>
                                </p:inputText>
                                <p:growl for="plotNo"/>
                            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
                            <td><p:outputLabel value="Ryot No" for="ryotCode"/></td>
                            <td><p:inputText value="#{harvestRateBean.ryotNo}" size="15" id="ryotCode" readonly="true" style="background: transparent;background-color: #cccccc"/></td>
```

My Bean Class:

```
public class HarvestRateBean implements Serializable {

private Map<String, String> seasons;
private Map<String, String> plants;
private String selectedPlant;
private String selectedSeason;
private String sapPlotNo;
private String ryotNo;

public HarvestRateBean() {
    seasons = new HashMap<String, String>();
    plants = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
public Map<String, String> getSeasons() {
    List<Season> season_list = loadSeason();
    for (Iterator<Season> it = season_list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

        Season season1 = it.next();

        seasons.put(season1.getSeason(), season1.getSeason());
    }
    return seasons;
}

public void setSeasons(Map<String, String> seasons) {
    this.seasons = seasons;
}
public List<Season> loadSeason() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Season> seasonlist = null;
    try {
        seasonlist = session.createCriteria(Season.class).list();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
    return seasonlist;
}

public Map<String, String> getPlants() {
    List<Plant> plant_list = loadPlants();
    for (Iterator<Plant> it = plant_list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

        Plant plant = it.next();

        plants.put(plant.getId().getPlant(), plant.getId().getPlant());
    }
    return plants;
}

public void setPlants(Map<String, String> plants) {
    this.plants = plants;
}

public List<Plant> loadPlants() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Plant> plantlist = null;
    try {
        plantlist = session.createCriteria(Plant.class).list();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return plantlist;
}
public String getSelectedPlant() {
    return selectedPlant;
}

public void setSelectedPlant(String selectedPlant) {
    this.selectedPlant = selectedPlant;
}

public String getSelectedSeason() {
    return selectedSeason;
}

public void setSelectedSeason(String selectedSeason) {
    this.selectedSeason = selectedSeason;
}

public String getSapPlotNo() {
    return sapPlotNo;
}

public void setSapPlotNo(String sapPlotNo) {
    this.sapPlotNo = sapPlotNo;
}

public String getRyotNo() {
    return ryotNo;
}

public void setRyotNo(String ryotNo) {
    this.ryotNo = ryotNo;
}   
public void loadPlotDetails {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<HarvesterRate> rateList = null;
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        if (getSelectedSeason() == null || getSelectedSeason().isEmpty()) {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Season is required", ""));
        } else if (getSelectedPlant() == null || getSelectedPlant().isEmpty()) {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Plant is required", ""));
        } else if (getSapPlotNo() == null || getSapPlotNo().isEmpty()) {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Plot No is required", ""));
        } else {
            rateList = session.createCriteria(HarvesterRate.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id.season", getSelectedSeason())).add(Restrictions.eq("id.plant", getSelectedPlant())).add(Restrictions.eq("id.plotNo", getSapPlotNo())).list();

            if (rateList.size() > 0) {
                for (Iterator<HarvesterRate> it = rateList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    HarvesterRate harvesterRate = it.next();
        setSapPlotNo(harvestRate.getPlotNo());
        setRyotNo(harvestRate.getVendorCode());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`getSelectedSeason()` and `getSelectedPlant()` always return null in `ajax` Call but I Called same method using `CommandButton` it return Selected value and everything works fine.

Comment: You don't need to plot the code not actually relate to the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p:ajax>` will by default process only the parent `ClientBehavior` component, which is in your particular case the `<p:inputText>`. In other words, the actual value of `<p:ajax process>` is `@this`. If you actually want to process the entire form, then you should be using `@form` as in

```
<p:inputText ...> 
    <p:ajax process="@form" ... />
</p:inputText>
```

The `process` attribute of `<p:commandButton>` defaults to `@form`, that's why it works therewith.

Or, if you have more input components in the form and intend to process only the input and those two dropdowns, then you can specify the (relative) client IDs space separated:

```
<p:inputText ...> 
    <p:ajax process="crushingSeason plant @this" ... />
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Implement `ajaxEvent` in `bean` class**

Ajax event is not like normal method rather than it invokes the listeners as input, you can configure the `Blur` action on a text field as following

**In JSF page**

```
<p:inputText id="name" value="#{loginBean.name}">
        <f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{loginBean.ajaxEvent}" /> 
</p:inputText>
```

Ensure that the above must be inside in `<h:form>`

**In ManagedBean class**

```
 public void ajaxEvent(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) 
 {
       //Do your stuffs
 }
```

Know more about JSF start from [here](https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz)

Comment: The argument is not required. Besides, OP didn't state anywhere that the ajax call threw `javax.el.MethodNotFoundException`, so the missing argument is hardly the probable cause here.